# Can't change title field display name

Tags: content-type, visual-studio, elements-xml

I'm using visual studio to develop custom content type, which uses Element as base content type. I'd like to change title field's display name, by doing so:

```
<FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" DisplayName="Foo" Required="TRUE"/>
```

But there is still **Title** instead of **Foo**. What can I do to make it work?

**EDIT:**

After looking into question and responses from SO, which *Nikhil* posted in his comment, I assume that what I want to do can be done only by changing display name of title field in list definition, not in content type field reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268843/renaming-title-column-in-sharepoint-list-definition

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/cant-rename-title-field-in-list-definition

Comment: Not enough..must be added as well as <Field>: <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Foo" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update is correct, you can rename the field in your list schema.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Inherits attribute that is giving you grief. Check out this blog post:

[Custom Content Types and Inherits in SharePoint 2010](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/05/02/custom-content-types-and-inherits-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)