# Can't rename "Title" field in List Definition

Tags: web-part, elements-xml, schema

I can't rename "Title" field to "Unit Type"
Here is my Schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="PrCenter - StatisticsDef" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/StatisticsQ" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
  <ContentTypes>
  <ContentType ID ="0x01002CCB015A81EA4b50B445D1137526F34F" Name ="Statistic Item" Description="Add new Item" Group="$Resources:List_Content_Types" Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID ="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Unit Type" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" DisplayName="Unit Type" Sealed="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Unit Type" Sealed="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{65887341-A389-40fd-BC3D-731897373EAE}" Name="Unit" DisplayName="Unit" Required="FALSE"/>          
      <FieldRef ID ="{8C88B284-BA34-434e-BADE-6F3D7E48F6D6}" Name="Date" DisplayName="Date" Required="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{94FBE6DC-1085-4fd7-8917-07C1FDFE5F93}" Name="InterfaceType" DisplayName="Interface Type" Required="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{A473E1A6-0109-4f77-9C09-5F09CB658960}" Name="InterfaceTitle" DisplayName="Interface Title" Required="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef ID ="{A1E79011-855F-45e9-9893-3105DB21B881}" Name="DisconnectionTime" DisplayName="Disconnection Time" Required="FALSE" Format="DateTime" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{FF267825-EBAB-41b9-A26D-C84C0259999E}" Name="ConnectionTime" DisplayName="Connection Time" Required="FALSE" Format="DateTime" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{8934395A-B122-400f-9116-5CA26C45C143}" Name="Comments" DisplayName="Comments" Required="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef ID ="{A947DA07-6D50-47e9-95CF-A849D5D751E5}" Name="FileID" DisplayName="File ID" Required="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef ID ="{C1420AAB-3B19-423c-A3CB-72D3C29DA595}" Name="Disconnection" DisplayName="Disconnection" Required="FALSE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Format="DateTime" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{3F07F022-B114-41c9-99D0-CCCF9548B487}" Name="Connection" DisplayName="Connection" Required="FALSE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Format="DateTime" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{063B6550-ECDD-4833-847B-CECAFAFF7F3F}" Name="Processed" DisplayName="Processed" Required="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{63933EB7-62B4-40bd-903F-33E87BFBCCE0}" Name="Accepted" DisplayName="Accepted" Required="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" />
      <FieldRef ID ="{A33702DF-327C-414e-8E76-614DB94F80E6}" Name="DurationSeconds" Required="FALSE" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListForm</Display>
          <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
          <New>ListForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
    <Folder TargetName="Item" />
  </ContentTypeRef>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
</ContentTypes>
<Fields>
  <Field DisplayName="Unit Type" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title"  Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" FromBaseType="TRUE" />
  <Field DisplayName="Unit Type" ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Type="Computed" Sealed="TRUE" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu" />        
  <Field DisplayName="Unit Type" ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Type="Computed" Sealed="TRUE" Name="LinkTitle" StaticName="LinkTitle" />

  <Field DisplayName="Unit" Type="Integer" Required="FALSE" ID="{65887341-A389-40fd-BC3D-731897373EAE}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="Unit" Name="Unit" ColName="int1" RowOrdinal="0" />
  <Field DisplayName="Date" Type="DateTime" Required="FALSE" ID="{8C88B284-BA34-434e-BADE-6F3D7E48F6D6}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="Date" Name="Date" ColName="datetime1" RowOrdinal="0" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" CalType="0" Format="DateOnly" />
  <Field DisplayName="Interface Type" Type="Text" Required="FALSE" ID="{94FBE6DC-1085-4fd7-8917-07C1FDFE5F93}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="InterfaceType" Name="InterfaceType" ColName="nvarchar3" RowOrdinal="0" />
  <Field DisplayName="Interface Title" Type="Text" Required="FALSE" ID="{A473E1A6-0109-4f77-9C09-5F09CB658960}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="InterfaceTitle" Name="InterfaceTitle" ColName="nvarchar4" RowOrdinal="0" />
  <Field DisplayName="Disconnection Time" Type="DateTime" Required="FALSE" ID="{A1E79011-855F-45e9-9893-3105DB21B881}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="DisconnectionTime" Name="DisconnectionTime" ColName="datetime2" RowOrdinal="0" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" CalType="0" Format="DateTime" />
  <Field DisplayName="Connection Time" Type="DateTime" Required="FALSE" ID="{FF267825-EBAB-41b9-A26D-C84C0259999E}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="ConnectionTime" Name="ConnectionTime" ColName="datetime3" RowOrdinal="0" />
  <Field DisplayName="Comments" Type="Note" Required="FALSE" ID="{8934395A-B122-400f-9116-5CA26C45C143}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="Comments" Name="Comments" ColName="ntext2" RowOrdinal="0" />
  <Field DisplayName="File ID" Type="Integer" Required="FALSE" ID="{A947DA07-6D50-47e9-95CF-A849D5D751E5}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="FileID" Name="FileID" ColName="int2" RowOrdinal="0" />
  <Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="Disconnection" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" LCID="1033" ResultType="DateTime" ReadOnly="TRUE" ID="{C1420AAB-3B19-423c-A3CB-72D3C29DA595}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="Disconnection" Name="Disconnection" ColName="sql_variant2" RowOrdinal="0" Required="FALSE">
    <Formula>=TEXT(DisconnectionTime,"dd MMM, HH:mm:ss")</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="DisconnectionTime" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
  <Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="Connection" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" LCID="1033" ResultType="DateTime" ReadOnly="TRUE" ID="{3F07F022-B114-41c9-99D0-CCCF9548B487}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="Connection" Name="Connection" ColName="sql_variant3" RowOrdinal="0" Required="FALSE">
    <Formula>=TEXT(ConnectionTime,"dd MMM, HH:mm:ss")</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="ConnectionTime" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
  <Field Name="Processed" FromBaseType="FALSE" Type="Choice" DisplayName="Processed" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" FillInChoice="FALSE" ID="{063B6550-ECDD-4833-847B-CECAFAFF7F3F}" StaticName="Processed" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" ColName="nvarchar5" RowOrdinal="0">
    <Default>false</Default>
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>true</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>false</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
  <Field Name="Accepted" FromBaseType="FALSE" Type="Choice" DisplayName="Accepted" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" FillInChoice="FALSE" ID="{63933EB7-62B4-40bd-903F-33E87BFBCCE0}" StaticName="Accepted" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" ColName="nvarchar6" RowOrdinal="0">
    <Default>false</Default>
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>true</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>false</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
  <Field Type="Number" DisplayName="DurationSeconds" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" ID="{A33702DF-327C-414e-8E76-614DB94F80E6}" SourceID="{$ListId:Lists/StatisticsQ;}" StaticName="DurationSeconds" Name="DurationSeconds" ColName="float1" RowOrdinal="0" />
</Fields>
<Views>
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>        
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>        
      <FieldRef Name="Unit" />
      <FieldRef Name="Date" />
      <FieldRef Name="InterfaceType" />
      <FieldRef Name="InterfaceTitle" />
      <FieldRef Name="Comments" />
      <FieldRef Name="FileID" />
      <FieldRef Name="Disconnection" />
      <FieldRef Name="Connection" />
      <FieldRef Name="Processed" />
      <FieldRef Name="Accepted" />
      <FieldRef Name="DurationSeconds" />
    </ViewFields>        
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
  </View>
</Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
</MetaData>
</List>
```

May be you need Elements.xml also :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List Definition project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
 <ListTemplate
  Name="StatisticsDef"
  Type="100"
  BaseType="0"
  OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
  SecurityBits="11"
  DisplayName="PrCenter - Statistics"
  Description="List created for Statistics Logs">    
 </ListTemplate>
</Elements>
```

1. I fixed this field via SharePoint Manager tool. Saved. Copied the code. Created List - I've got "Title".
2. I fixed field from Sharepoint site. Went back to SharePoint Manager tool. Copied the Code. Created list - I've got "Title"... I don't understand this magic.

My be anyone has correct schema.xml with renamed "Title" field so I can grab it???
Thank you for help!!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using wrong identifiers for the three fields Title, LinkTitle and LinkTitleNoMenu.
The correct ones should be:

- **Title**             ---  fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247
- **LinkTitleNoMenu**         ---  bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d
- **LinkTitle**   ---  82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31

I have tried to search for the guid you are using instead, but google brings up no results (only this question). Can you try and use the correct ids and see if this fix your problem?

PS: when in dubt about the identifier for a buil-in field, you can refer to [Frodes list of SharePoint column field ids](http://aarebrot.net/blog/2010/06/frodes-awesome-list-of-sharepoint-column-field-ids-for-sharepoint-2010/) - it should contain the info for any field you may need. If you are working in codebehind you may also use the [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.aspx) class.

**EDIT:**
Still not working... As far as I know, it should work if you rename the three field Title, LinkTitleNoMenu, LinkTitle (see those link: [first](http://alottolearn.net/2012/02/14/rename-title-in-a-sharepoint-list/), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750589/sharepoint-title-column-displayname),[third](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30653/renaming-title-column-in-sharepoint-list-definition), [fourth](http://spandothers.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/renaming-the-title-column-in-a-sharepoint-list/) - renaming only the title column is the most common problem).
Assuming that there aren't any other error that I haven't noticed, I am starting to belive that there is something in your caml definition that is making SharePoint ignore same of the declaration (also known as "If you set the inherith parameter in a doc set content type definition, I will ignore all the declaration"...). I know this isn't much, but I suggest that you try to remove all "useless" part from the declaration and see if this change anything. For example, try to leave only the id and display name in the  declaration. Also, check if there is any messed up character in the declaration - sometimes if you copy&paste the code from somewhere else a non-printable char may end up in the caml, and SharePoint doesn't like them (I know, discovered first person some time ago...).

I will see if I find some time to test your declaration.

Comment: I've updated id's , but still "Title"... I've placed these fields in <FieldRefs> and in <Fields> too, but result is the same "Title"...

Comment: **fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247** Title,  **bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d** LinkTitleNoMenu, **82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31** LinkTitle  ..... Did you mix-up  LinkTitleNoMenu and LinkTitle  ID's?

Comment: Yes, they were inverted - usual copy/paste error we all love and fear. Now it is corrected, thanks for the notice.

Comment: So))  anyway "Title" is still "Title" any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, give me some more time - i'm doubleckeching some other source. In the meantime, if you have access to the tool SharePoint Manager you could rename the field in the ui and then compare the list caml definition reported from the tool with the one you wrote.

Comment: no I don't have SharePoint Manager tool... I'll search for it and try. I'll let you know.

Comment: 1. I fixed this field via SharePoint Manager tool. Saved. Copied the code. Created List - I've got "Title".   2. I fixed field from Sharepoint site. Went back to SharePoint Manager tool. Copied the Code. Created list - I've got "Title"... I don't understand this magic. My be anyone has correct schema.xml with renamed "Title" field so I can grab it???

Answer (score 1):

changes apply on any other fields except this Primary key !!! field because it is a reference.

But before create this list, it is possible by change with new content type that you should create new one in your site application

then correct GUID's for

```
Title --- fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247
LinkTitle --- bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d
LinkTitleNoMenu --- 82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31
```

Comment: But why can I cahnge it later in design mode and no restrictions appear then? Do you mean that I can rename it only after creation?

Comment: Maybe it's because in Lists , this field , function as edit as link to as view as ... in the view .

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38219/cant-hide-the-title-column-in-a-custom-content-type

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/cant-change-title-field-display-name

Comment: I've updated my code. Result is the same :(

Comment: Ps: if you took the field id from the old version of my answer, you should fix them as for Lena comment. I had inverted two values when copying the ids.

Answer (score 0):

In the  element, where Title is declared, keep the display name as Title then in the reference , that's where you'll specify your own text:

      ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything under `FieldRefs` shouldn't be modified.

```
<ContentType ID ="0x01002CCB015A81EA4b50B445D1137526F34F" Name ="Statistic Item" Description="Add new Item" Group="$Resources:List_Content_Types" Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef ID ="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Title" Required="TRUE" />
        <FieldRef ID ="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" DisplayName="LinkTitleNoMenu" Sealed="TRUE" />
        <FieldRef ID ="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="LinkTitle" Sealed="TRUE" />
        (...)
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
```

To change the Display Name of a field you simply change it's `DisplayName` in it's corresponding `Field` tag, just under `Fields`.

```
<Fields>
    <Field DisplayName="Unit Type" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title"  Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" FromBaseType="TRUE" />
    <Field DisplayName="Unit Type" ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Type="Computed" Sealed="TRUE" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu" />        
    <Field DisplayName="Unit Type" ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" Type="Computed" Sealed="TRUE" Name="LinkTitle" StaticName="LinkTitle" />
    (...)
</fields>
```